# Picture stretching, map, capital letter

Tags: php, jquery, google-maps

I have Question to ask regarding Php, goole map, jquery

1> I was working on localhost and whenever i click on localhost/xyz/about.php and  localhost/xyz/About.php (about and About) its working.. but in godaddy web server when i change letter to capital one like about.php to About.php it is not working why?

2> I wanted to code like whenever someone click on [Feed My location Box] so by Google map it current location can be retrieve and feed the latitude and longitude in database.
Any link to learn or script?

3>Very very Important.
I wanted to make a cover picture on my project but i am getting irritated because its stretching, and making picture ugly, how Facebook upload a cover pic without streching